# How can I get right-alignment to work in a div inside a table cell for IE 7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, alignment, css-float

`Float:right` specified for a `div` inside a table cell seems to have no effect in IE. I have also tried text-align right, among other things, to align the layer contents to the right, but without success in IE 7.

CSS snippet:

```
.workloadcell {
    background-color: #E6D7E9;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 16px;
    text-align: right;
}

div.workload {
    background-color: #E6D7E9;
    text-align: right;
    width: 14px;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML snippet:

```
<td class="workloadcell">
    <div class="workload">
        1
    </div>
</td>
```

Both the HTML and the CSS validate, and in Firefox the text aligns right, as it should. If you want to test the complete code by copy/pasting it, it's here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Table Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}


.workloadcell {
    background-color: #E6D7E9;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 16px;
    text-align: right;
}



div.workload {
    background-color: #E6D7E9;
    text-align: right;
    width: 14px;
    float: right;
}
</style>
    </head>



<body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div>
                        2008
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        Q1
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        Q2
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        Q3
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        Q4
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    workload forecast
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        1
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        2
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        2
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        2
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    actual workload
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        3
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        3
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        2
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="workloadcell">
                    <div class="workload">
                        3
                    </div>
                </td>
                        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I know that the CSS is are not optimal in the sense that the class declarations are repeated for several elements, but please don't comment on this, if it is not relevant to the problem.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work the way you have it (or the way alexmeia suggests).

But, (this being IE), the *headers* Q1, Q2, etc. are pushing the table columns wider than the 14 px you've requested.

The columns are right justified within the 14px you've defined, but the divs are not moving to the right in IE. (The div is staying within the 14px defined for it even though the column is *actually* wider than 14px)

To illustrate this, you can either make the width say 28px **or** change the color of one of the backgrounds to demonstrate the difference between the td and the div within in.

```
.workloadcell {
    background-color: #E6D7E9;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 16px;
    text-align: right;
}

div.workload {
    background-color: #E6EEE9;
    text-align: right;
    width: 14px;
    float: right;
}
```

The solution for IE is to either not define a width *or* to make it wide enough to accomodate the header.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  Helped me track down a bug while facing a deadline today.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to declare rules for the div.workload.
Use only this rules and everything will work fine:

```
 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
     }

 .workloadcell {
    background-color: #E6D7E9;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 16px;
    text-align: right;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, it seems to work because the width is increased from 14px to 20px. I already specified the padding as 0px for the table cell, so one could think there should be enough room for right-alignment also with 14px wide cell. Is there some explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting, that IE, especially v6 on pre SP1 XP, and older windows has serious rendering issues when you intermingle tables within divs, and divs within those tables.  Once you exceed a certain complexity & nesting you may get a blank/white page.

If your needing to right-align text content in certain cells, I would suggest adding an additional class declaration to the td tag, not nesting a div.  I would also suggest trying in  IE8, and see if the issue persists.  You didn't mention which versions you need to support.